# How to delete one value of keys from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, del

I'm trying to delete a specific input of user using del function but it deletes the whole key values below it

```
for account3 in accounts:
    print("\t   ", account3["Name"].ljust(25), account3["Username"].ljust(27), account3["Password"])

    userinput = input('Account Name you want to delete: ')
    for account4 in accounts:
        if userinput == account4["Name"]:
            userinput = input('Re-enter name to confirm: ')

            for account5 in accounts:
                if userinput == account5["Name"]:
                    del account5["Name"], account5["Username"], account5["Password"]
                    print('Deleted Successfully!')
                    menu()
                    break
```

After the user confirms the deletion, it deletes all values in the dictionary and gives a `key error: "name"`. Is there any way to delete only the information given by the user?

Comment: You want the key itself to stay but the value to be gone? Just set the value to `None` then... Also your loops are overly complicated when you can do key lookups in dictionaries.

Comment: I'm trying to delete one set of information from user input but the other user inputs will stay. only the selected one will go. that's what trying to do sir

Answer (score 0):

Setting the values to `None` is what you want instead of deleting the entries.

Replace the `del` line with this.

```
account5["Name"], account5["Username"], account5["Password"] = None, None, None
```

Comment: gives an error NoneType

Comment: This is the way to change that exact line. As I already pointed out your loops are unnecessarily complex. You are also not showing us the data structure or other relevant parts of your code. So it make it to where you get a standard answer and not one tailored to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to loop through the list multiple times to find the matching account, I suggest building a dict that maps the name to each account, and using `accounts.remove()` to remove the account.

```
accounts_by_name = {account["Name"]: account for account in accounts}

for account in accounts:
    print("\t   ", account3["Name"].ljust(25), account3["Username"].ljust(27), account3["Password"])
    name = input("Account name you want to delete: ")
    if name not in accounts_by_name:
        continue
    if input("Re-enter name to confirm: ") != name:
        continue
    accounts.remove(accounts_by_name[name])
    menu()
    break
```

Comment: the code doesn't go through, since my user inputs dictionary are appended on a List, accounts= [ ], I want to remove only the value for example there names in my dict 'john', 'allen' then the user wanted to remove john from the dictionary. so then when I print my dict, allen would only appear in the dictionary.

Comment: Maybe you could include a value for `accounts` in your question and explain what you want it to look like after an account has been removed?  It's not possible to infer the desired behavior from your existing code since your existing code doesn't work.